# Display .swf image file from database using ASP.net handler

Tags: asp.net, flash, handler

I'm having a great deal of difficulty here trying to display a .swf image-based file in IE7 using an ASP.net handler or another means of displaying a binary .swf file (i.e. from a database). Utilizing an HTTP handler(Handler.ashx) I was hoping to navigate to that url and display the .swf image, similar to opening the .swf file utilizing the browser. I simply cannot get this to work...

I have tried many different methods in order to display these values, they are listed below, followed by a snippet of code that is similar to what I am using in my application.

> 1) When changing the content-disposition value in the header to use an
>   attachment, the .swf file will be saved and can be opened using the
>   browser.
>
> 2) When utilizing a .png file with a content type of "image/png" this
>   works perfectly.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    Byte[] swfFile = File.ReadAllBytes("file.swf");

    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=file.swf");
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(swfFile);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: how you initialize it on the web page ? Do you have place it inside an object on html page ? Its a flash file, you can not just throw it as it is.

Comment: I tried embedding it into an object and referencing the ashx page in the source, something like this: <object width="400" height="400"><embed src="handler.ashx"></embed></object>

Comment: I would recommend using a request monitor like Fiddler, Charles, etc. to see the response headers for an on-disk .swf; then just duplicate those in your handler.

Answer (score 0):

You code will work perfectly in Chorme browser. But not in IE8, or Firefox 27.
Instead of flusing the object directly to the page, have a page with `OBJECT` tag and call another web page to get the SWF stream.

1. Page with `OBJECT` element

`<object classid=clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
     codebase="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/" 
     width="100%" height="100%" id="myMovieName" >
    <param name="movie" value="http://PageWhichGivesObjectStream.aspx?id=1"/> 
    <param name="quality" value="high"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <param name="play" value="true"/>
    <param name="loop" value="true"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="salign" value="l"/>
  </object>`

1. Page which gives object stream

   `Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash"
   Response.BinaryWrite(FlashObjectBinary)
   Response.End()`

This works in IE8